# How To Use Link_to and why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails and none of the answers I've seen addressed my issue, and no question is specific enough for me

I'm attempting to use the `<%= link_to %>`helper on rails but it always says

> undefined local variable or method trainer_index

For class i am creating a pokemon game,

my controllers, models and views look something like this:

```
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── login_controller.rb
│   │   └── trainer_controller.rb
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── login.rb
│   │   └── trainer.rb
│   └── views
│       ├── logins
│       │   ├── create.html.erb
│       │   ├── index.html.erb
│       │   ├── show.html.erb
│       │   ├── update.html.erb
│       └── trainers
│           ├── index.html.erb
│           ├── show.html.erb
│           ├── create.html.erb
│           ├── destroy.html.erb
```

*#config/routes.rb*

```
resources :login do
  resources :trainer
end
```

how would I format my `link_to` helper to link a button in my:

```
views/login/show
```

to my:

```
views/trainers/index
```

and why?

meaning in *link_to "name", something_path*

am I referencing my controller, my view, or my model?

Comment: Thank You So Much Everyone!, All Of Your Answers Together Gave Me Exactly The Clarity I Needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you always run the command in terminal `rails routes` (or `rake routes`) and take a look to [Rails routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), understanding also [CRUD verbs and actions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

`rails routes` takes also an argument `-c` (controller) so you can show the routes to the controller.

---

While you read the guide, run the command for your app, starting from the top level: `rails routes -c login`, it'll output:

```
#      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
# login_index GET    /login(.:format)          login#index
#             POST   /login(.:format)          login#create
#   new_login GET    /login/new(.:format)      login#new
#  edit_login GET    /login/:id/edit(.:format) login#edit
#       login GET    /login/:id(.:format)      login#show
#             PATCH  /login/:id(.:format)      login#update
#             PUT    /login/:id(.:format)      login#update
#             DELETE /login/:id(.:format)      login#destroy
```

- The first column you have the prefix to be used as [path or url helper](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) in `link_to`.
- The second columns shows the corresponding CRUD verb.
- The URI column shows how the URI string is formatted: you cn see there is an :id which is supposed to be the id of the resource (in this case the `id` of `login` object or the object itself, often passed as variable `@login`).
- The last column shows the related controller and the method in the controller.

For example `#       login GET    /login/:id(.:format)      login#show` means:

- There is a controller file logins_controller.rb
- The controller defines a method show: `def show; end`
- There is a view folder `app\views\logins\show.html.erb
- You can reach the page at `login\123` which shows the `Login` object whit `id = 123`
- In controller the `:id` parameter is available as params[:id] and its the value is 123

---

For the nested case of `trainer`, run `rails routes -c trainer`:

```
#              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
# login_trainer_index GET    /login/:login_id/trainer(.:format)          trainer#index
#                     POST   /login/:login_id/trainer(.:format)          trainer#create
#   new_login_trainer GET    /login/:login_id/trainer/new(.:format)      trainer#new
#  edit_login_trainer GET    /login/:login_id/trainer/:id/edit(.:format) trainer#edit
#       login_trainer GET    /login/:login_id/trainer/:id(.:format)      trainer#show
#                     PATCH  /login/:login_id/trainer/:id(.:format)      trainer#update
#                     PUT    /login/:login_id/trainer/:id(.:format)      trainer#update
#                     DELETE /login/:login_id/trainer/:id(.:format)      trainer#destroy
```

The story is the same, but now you have one parameter more:

- **`:id`** (`params[:id]`) which is referred to the controller object, in this case `trainer`, so it can refer to the model `Trainer`.
- **`:login_id`** (`params[:login_id]`) which is referred to `login` object, so you could use to find the record in the related model: `@login = Login.find(params[:login_id])`.

From the table you can see that if you want to show all trainers:

```
# login_trainer_index GET    /login/:login_id/trainer(.:format)          trainer#index
```

Your path helper is

```
login_trainer_index_path(@login.login_id)
```

or just `login_trainer_index_path(@login)` where `@login` is assigned in `index` method of `trainers_controller.rb` as `@login = Login.find(params[:login_id]`

If you want to show a specific `trainer` you should look into GET:

```
#       login_trainer GET    /login/:login_id/trainer/:id(.:format)      trainer#show
```

so the helper path is similar to (note the two params):

```
login_trainer_path(@login, @trainer)
```

You can pass also the `id` of `Login` and `Trainer` as arguments for the helper, depending on what's better for you do to in `show` method of `trainers_controller.rb`

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stack overflow!
In Rails you use the `link_to` helper instead of the `</a>` tag from html. But the link_to also just generates an html a-tag with the right attributes. 
Use it like so:

```
<%= link_to "Text on the link", path %>
```

Now in order to find the right path (the `href` attribute of the link). You need to find the right prefix for your routes. There is a terminal command you can use to find it out: `rails routes` run it in your terminal and see a nice table of your routes, which controller actions they're routed to and their prefixes.

Since you have nested routes your prefix should be something like:
`login_trainers` for the trainer#index action. Now why do we use the link to helper. It becomes clear, when you have a closer look at the route for trainer index: `login/:login_id/trainers`. Meaning, that there is a dynamic part in the url, representing the id of the respective record.
The link_to then needs an id (or the whole instance) in order to build the right a-tag.
So you can build the link_to:

```
<%= link_to "All trainers", login_trainers_path(@login) %>
```

`@login` coming from the controller.

One last tip: why do you nest your routes under login? Do you take care of the login into your app yourself? You should have a look at the devise gem, it is an authentication gem and is super cool!